# Counting occurrences of a substring on Tcl 8.0

Tags: string, tcl

I'm trying to figure out how many times one string occurs in another, which Tcl doesn't seem to have built-in. I can't use either of the solutions on the [wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/37861), since I have to support Tcl 8.0.

This doesn't work:

```
# needleString is known to contain no regex metacharacters
llength [regexp -all -inline $needleString $haystackString]
```

because `-all` isn't supported on 8.0.

This doesn't work:

```
proc string_occurrences {needleString haystackString} {

    set j [string first $needleString $haystackString 0]
    if {$j == -1} {return 0}

    set i 0
    while {$j != -1 } {
        set j [string first $needleString $haystackString [incr j]]
        incr i
    }

    return $i
}
```

because `string first` doesn't support the `startIndex` argument on 8.0.

I could modify `string_occurrences` to use `string range` to take substrings of the string and 2-argument `string first` to search inside those, but that's even more cumbersome than the loop already is, and I don't know how efficient `string range` is. Do I have any better options?

Comment: 8.0? Woah! You're flying solo without a ground crew here…

Comment: @DonalFellows: I wish I wasn't stuck with a version from 1997, but that's what our testing infrastructure says it's using.

Comment: tcl 8.0 man pages: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.0/TclCmd/contents.htm

Comment: I was stuck on Tcl 8.0 in a previous job: it was the version embedded in the database, so no upgrade path. Oddly, it was still faster to process large queries in Tcl rather than the builtin query language. Happy to not have to work with that anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `[regsub -all]` (which is present in 8.0) to create a new string with the needleString removed, and compare lengths:

```
proc string_occurrences {needleString haystackString} {
    regsub -all $needleString $haystackString {} stripped
    expr {([string length $haystackString] - [string length $stripped]) / [string length $needleString]}
}
```